# CSS translateY just doesnt work on one single element

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

As you can see, i have 4 Different h1-Elements that have to fadeIn one after another:

HTML:

`

```
    <div id="header-headlines">

        <h1>FIRST HL</h1>

        <h1>SECOND HL,</h1>
        <h1>THIRD HL,</h1>
        <h1>FOURTH HL<span id="changing-headline">WORD 1</span> ?</h1>

    </div>

    <div id="header-picture-wrapper">

        <div class="sub-wrapper-relative">

            <div id="header-circle-frame"><div id="circle-frame-content"></div></div>

            <img id="pic-me" src="./img/me/portfolio-Profile-M-tablet-size-responsive.png" alt="some text">

        </div>

    </div>

</header>`
```

CSS:

`header {

```
background-image: radial-gradient(at 80% 80%, var(--secon2), var(--prim));

position: relative;

height: 90vh;

min-height: 500px;

overflow: hidden;
```

}
#header-headlines {

```
position: relative;

top: 60%;

left: 5%;

transform: translateY(-50%);

width: 100%;

height: 70%;
```

}
#header-headlines h1 {

```
font-size: clamp(60px, 6vmax, 70px);

color: #ddd;
```

}
#header-headlines h1:first-child {

```
font-size: clamp(70px, 6.5vmax, 80px);

text-decoration: overline;

letter-spacing: 1rem;

opacity: 0;

animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in 1;
```

}

#header-headlines h1:nth-child(2) {

```
opacity: 0;

animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in .2s 1;
```

}
#header-headlines h1:nth-child(3) {

```
opacity: 0;

animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in .4s 1;
```

}

#header-headlines h1:last-child {

```
opacity: 0;

animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in .6s 1;
```

}

#changing-headline {

```
color: var(--tert1);

transform: translateX(50px) translateY(50px);

animation: wordChanger 1s linear 1.6s 4;
```

}`

those animations work. after the last one is done, i want that little span to do another animation for 4 times(as you can see at "#changing-headline" at the bottom of the css)

here is the CSS with the animations:

`@keyframes fadeIn {

```
0% {

    opacity: 0;

}

100% {

    opacity: 1;

}
```

}

@keyframes wordChanger {

```
0% {

    transform: translateY(0);

    opacity: 1;

}
50% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
}
55% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
    opacity: 0;
}
100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

}`

Because the instant value of those headlines is opacity: 0, they would dissappear again after the animation, so i set a timer that gives every h1 element opacity of 1 AFTER the animations have finished:

`let headlines = document.querySelectorAll("#header-headlines h1");

for(let i = 0 ; i < headlines.length ; i++)

{
switch(i)

```
{

    case 0:

        setTimeout(() => {

            headlines[i].style.opacity = "1";

        }, 1000);

        break;

    case 1:

        setTimeout(() => {

            headlines[i].style.opacity = "1";

        }, 1200);

        break;

    case 2:

        setTimeout(() => {

            headlines[i].style.opacity = "1";

        }, 1400);

        break;

    case 3:

        setTimeout(() => {

            headlines[i].style.opacity = "1";

        }, 1600);

        break;

}
```

}`

the second animation(wordChanger) makes sure, that the word changes afterevery re-appearing of #word-changer and, like the name says, with another word. Thats the JS i used for setting new words:

`let wordChange = document.getElementById("changing-headline"); setTimeout(() => { wordChange.innerText = "WORD 2"; }, 2600);`

he animates the opacity, but it just doenst move. i deleted that animation and just hardcoded some different "transform: translate-Values into #changing-headline, but nothing happens.
First i thought i misstyped the id name, or the transform attribute, but it works super fine with ALL the other elements.

i also tried it with px, %, em, rem but nothing happens, but ONLY WITH #changing-headline
So why isnt #changing-headline moving?

[even th inspector shows no issues, its like it works how it should](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKBK3.jpg)

Comment: To quote **blocks** of code use triple-backticks ``` not just one ` which is for _inline_ code.

Comment: i got the answer....seems like inline-elements doesnt like translate()